# Python how to parse out values in a json response object

Tags: python, json, get

Trying to pull out data from a json response.  The response contains extra square brackets that might be casing this issue?

```
if debug: print "add_context_object Request: " + repr(response.url)
if debug: print "add_context_object Response: " + repr(response.content)
result = json.loads(response.content)
print result
print "Starting parse..."
wrapper = result.get("RoutingObj" , result)
```

`add_context_object` Response:

```
'[[{"RoutingObj": {"serialVersionUID":1,"balance":30000.0,"delinquency":null,"routeType":"Platinum"}}]]'
```

`json.loads` returns:

```
[[{u'RoutingObj': {u'delinquency': None, u'balance': 30000.0, u'routeType': u'Platinum', u'serialVersionUID': 1}}]]
```

The code errors out indicating its a list:

```
wrapper = result.get("RoutingObj" , result)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Thanks, also found that adding the index when initially setting result worked: 'result = eval(response.content)[0][0]'  Its probably not as flexible as the the answers below but I don't see a reason why the web service will ever return multiple index's.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression to get the json out from between the [[ and ]], those square brackets are causing python to think it's a list in a list